FastAPI + Async DB calls + Async response to client
I have code already for using FastAPI and making an async call to the database.
Next I need to trigger an async call to the database (to create or update) and also trigger a response to the client calling my API in an async way, so that each process runs separately and does not wait for the other one to complete.
How can I do this, if it's possible?
Here is an example FastAPI endpoint - it is not a perfect example, but shows how I'm sending async updates to the database.  How would I also send a response to the client in an async manner? (assume that the code calls an LLM and once the response from the LLM is received, the code wants to update the DB and also send some of the LLM's response back to the client.)
That code is not present, but the async call to the database is present, as well as a "return" to the client. Assume that what I want to return to the client is not dependent on the database call, but came back from the LLM.
Essentially, I'm asking for the async "pattern" to send a response while also updating the database.
async def update_conversation_title(conversation_id: UUID, title: Annotated[str, Body(embed=True)], session: AsyncSession = Depends(db.get_session)):
    logger.info(f"get_conversations_by_id() - Request Received, finding all Conversations for ID: {conversation_id}.")

    res = await db.update_db(session, m.Conversation, update_fields={'title': title}, constraints=[m.Conversation.id == conversation_id])
    print(res)
    # Something here to send LLM response to calling client in a async way...
    return res[0]


Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/ ? But if you're only updating the database, that should generally be a very fast process, so you're adding complexity for something that's probably not going to be a performance issue at all.

Please have a look at this answer, in order to better understand the concept of async/await, and how FastAPI deals with sync code as well. Next, please take a look at this answer, this answer, as well as this answer and this answer on how to run tasks in the background without blocking the event loop.
